# [c#]how do i make the Console read two strings in one line

Tags: c#, string, readline

I,m trying to make two strings be read by console readline as one line e.g.

```
string a,b=console.readLine();
Console.writeLine (a+b);
```

I keep getting that it doesn't recognize "a" as a string
I tried doing the "a" and "b" on a twice readline but it comes as two lines in the command line I want "a" and "b" to be one line in command

Answer (score 3):

What you currently have is the equivalent of

```
string a;  // a has no value and thus is undefined
string b = Console.ReadLine(); // b is the value of the input
```

To achieve your desired result of deriving both values of `a` and `b` from a single input line, you will need to come up with a way of parsing your input.

For example, what is the format of the input you're expecting? If it may be something like

`inputpart1 inputpart2`

you could derive the values of `a` and `b` by splitting the input by the space character, and defining the first part to `a` and the second to `b`

```
var inputParts = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');  // ["inputpart1", "inputpart2"]
string a = inputParts[0]; // "inputpart1"
string b = inputParts[1]; // "inputpart2"

Console.WriteLine(a+b);
// prints "inputpart1inputpart2"
```

But of course, the format of your input may be (and probably is) different so you will need to adjust how you parse it accordingly to derive your values for `a`, `b`.